# How do I capture the output of tSampleRow/tFileProperties?

Tags: talend

I have this flow where I am trying to fetch the details of the last modified file at the SFTP location. While I am able to do that and print the required file's name in the tLogRow component, I am not sure how to use that info to capture more details about the file / pass that info to the tFTPGet component. Any pointers?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the tSetGlobalVar with row11.CURRENT_FILE. Can use the global var now.